# Calling C from Fortran: ``void*`` return value

Tags: fortran

## How to call a `void *function(...)` from Fortran?

I am currently trying to call a few C functions from Fortran. I have done so before, but I have called only my own functions. For example, to call:

```
void add(int *csum, int *ca, int *cb) { *csum = *ca + *cb; }
```

from Fortran, I have used:

```
INTEGER :: fsum, fa, fb
CALL add(fsum, fa, fb)
```

**This works fine.** Now I have a couple of functions roughly like:

```
void *create_obj(void);
void use_obj(void *obj);
void free_obj(void *obj);
```

or even:

```
struct private_struct; /* defined somewhere else */
struct private_struct *create_p(void);
void use_p(struct private_struct *p);
void free_f(struct private_struct *p);
```

where the struct is private, i.e., I have no knowledge of its members.

***Question:*** How can I get the return values into Fortran? I do not really need to access them, but I must store them somehow during their `create`...`use`...`destroy` lifecycle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the object in C, pass a pointer to it to Fortran, then pass that pointer to C routines.  Finally, call a C routine to free the memory.  The ISO C Binding provides the Fortran type C_PTR.

Comment: Great! Exactly what I was looking for, this helped me solving this. Sorry if my question has been a stupid one (now that I see the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning a pointer to the object you can keep it in an array (or other container) inside the C library and return and index into the array (or whatever it fits your container).

```
int create_obj(); // returns the obj_id
void use_obj(int *obj_id);
void free_obj(int *obj_id);
```

You will have to keep count of what elements of the array are being used. Something like

```
struct Entry {
    bool used;
    struct Obj value; 
}
Entry objects[100];
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the index-to-C-array